# What's the difference \\.\C: and \\.\C:\

Tags: windows, file, file-io, path, filesystems

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx),

> String         Meaning
>   **\\.\C:**   Opens the C: volume.
>   **\\.\C:\** Opens the file system of the C: volume.

I could open **\\.\C:** volume device.
But I couldn't open **\\.\C:\** directory by CreateFile.

How can I open the directory by CreateFile with \\.\ prefix.
And if I open the directory, what can I do by using the handle.

Are **C:\** and **\\.\C:\** same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same MSDN page:

> When opening a volume or removable
>   media drive (for example, a floppy
>   disk drive or flash memory thumb
>   drive), the lpFileName string should
>   be the following form: \.\X:. Do not
>   use a trailing backslash (), which
>   indicates the root directory of a
>   drive. The following table shows some
>   examples of drive strings.

Most likely since the WinAPI does not support the trailing backslash they mean the same but behave differently